# take the data from the first match of date and last match of date to calculate a single day data

Tags: c#, postgresql, date

When I am using code written below it is taking last reading of the date in from_date and last reading of the date in to_date.
So if I want reading of a single day also ,I have to put two different dates.
I want the first reading of the date in from_date n last reading of the date in to_date.
If I put the same date in both the columns it should return the data of that single date.

```
dt2 = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(from_date));
dt3 = DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(to_date));
if (dt2.Date == dt1.Date)
{
    textBox2.Text = tileNo[19];   
}
if (dt3.Date == dt1.Date)
{
    textBox3.Text = tileNo[19];  
}
```

How can I do this???

Answer (score 0):

for the same date data, you can make

```
to_date = from_date.AddDays(1);
```

and then when you query for data use this logic

```
my_data = from row in table where row.Date>= from_date && row.Date < to_date select row;
```

Comment: I am looking for a general code which will work for a single day also n also for more then 1 day. I will leave it on user to enter date